# Custom Tree Item Using NatTable

Tags: swt, eclipse-rcp, nattable

I want to achieve following UI for tree item in a eclipse RCP e4 application

```
--------------------
|> Label     [image]
--------------------
     |> Label
     |> Label
     |> Label
---------------------
|> Label     [image]
---------------------
```

Here a row should be capable of having different background color as well as height.I searched for such custom tree item. JFace treeItem seems to have limitations for showing images on right side, so wondering if NatTable fits for such custom tree item. Any suggestion would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question was if NatTable fits for such a custom tree, and the answer is yes. As NatTable is a custom painted control that doesn't build on SWT Tables and Trees, you are mostly free to do whatever you want.

From your question you have 3 requirements:

1. different row heights -> NatTable supports this, SWT doesn't because of OS limitations
2. different background colors -> NatTable supports this via conditional styling
3. images on the right -> NatTable supports this via CellPainterDecorator

Comment: Thank you drik. is there any good tutorial for such thing? what I see here is blank :  http://www.eclipse.org/nattable/documentation.php?page=tree

Comment: Unfortunately there is no tutorial or documentation for trees in NatTable yet. I'm working on the whole documentation, but it is a lot of work, so the progress is quite slow.

On the linked resources page in our documentation you find a Getting Started tutorial on the web written in English and two German articles to get started (I wrote them when NatTable was hosted on SourceForge, so the examples won't work without several updates).
https://www.eclipse.org/nattable/documentation.php?page=articles

For now you could also look at our examples application linked on the homepage to get an idea.

Comment: Finally I am fully able to achieve what I intended, NatTable is amazing!

Answer (score 1):

From my experience customizing existing third party widgets is long and painful job. I almost always ended up with my own Tree and Table with custom paintListeners. If You want modify fonts, colors, background, alignments or images' placement I recommend creating simple SWT.Tree and add custom drawing.

Link to great tutorial:
http://www.eclipse.org/articles/article.php?file=Article-CustomDrawingTableAndTreeItems/index.html